# Microsoft API for contact list groups like those in OWA

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

In the `Outlook Web Application`, `OWA` for short (https://outlook.live.com/owa/) there is the feature of creating `lists` (`contact list groups`) where you can add members and a member can belong to more than one such list (I am not referring to contact folders).

My question is if there is a way to access those lists through a Microsoft API ( preferably `Outlook` or `Graph`).

To illustrate what I am talking about here is a partial screenshot from creating a new list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, these are not surfaced by either Graph or the Outlook APIs. I would suggest adding your vote(s) to the [existing UserVoice request for this feature](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/8560324-office365-api-allow-to-create-get-and-update-con) (these are actively tracked and a primary source for enhancements).